# Creating two separate executables from a makefile (g++)

Tags: c++, g++, makefile

Currently, I have my makefile set up to compile and make a fairly large project.  I have written a second cpp file with main function for running tests.  I want these to run separately, but build together and they use the same files.  How is this accomplished?

**edit**: As reference, here is my current makefile.  I'm not sure how to adjust it.

```
CC=g++
CFLAGS=-c -Wall -DDEBUG -g
LDFLAGS=
SOURCES=main.cpp Foo.cpp Bar.cpp Test.cpp A.cpp B.cpp C.cpp
OBJECTS=$(SOURCES:.cpp=.o)
EXECUTABLE=myprogram

all: $(SOURCES) $(EXECUTABLE)

$(EXECUTABLE): $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) $(OBJECTS) -o $@

.cpp.o:
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Normally you would just have multiple targets and do something like this:

```
.PHONY: all target tests

all: target tests

target: ...
    ...

tests: ...
    ...
```

Then you can just `make` (defaults to `make all`), or just `make target` or `make tests` as needed.

So for your makefile example above you might want to have something like this:

```
CC = g++
CFLAGS = -c -Wall -DDEBUG -g
LDFLAGS =
COMMON_SOURCES = Foo.cpp Bar.cpp A.cpp B.cpp C.cpp
TARGET_SOURCES = main.cpp
TEST_SOURCES = test_main.cpp
COMMON_OBJECTS = $(COMMON_SOURCES:.cpp=.o)
TARGET_OBJECTS = $(TARGET_SOURCES:.cpp=.o)
TEST_OBJECTS = $(TEST_SOURCES:.cpp=.o)
EXECUTABLE = myprogram
TEST_EXECUTABLE = mytestprogram

.PHONY: all target tests

all: target tests

target: $(EXECUTABLE)

tests: $(TEST_EXECUTABLE)

$(EXECUTABLE): $(COMMON_OBJECTS) $(TARGET_OBJECTS)
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) $^ -o $@

$(TEST_EXECUTABLE): $(COMMON_OBJECTS) $(TEST_OBJECTS)
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) $^ -o $@

.cpp.o:
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@
```

Comment: I'm sure this answer is right, but I am unexperienced with makefiles.  I've posted my current one in the post.  Should I have 2 "SOURCES=" lines (with different names, obviously), where 1 includes the main.cpp and one includes the testing main, and then for target reference the one with main?  Just a bit confused.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to do it:

```
CXXFLAGS += -std=c++11 -Wall -O3

all: myprog mytest

myprog.cpp: main.cpp
    cp -vf $< $@
myprog: myprog.o Foo.o Bar.o Test.o A.o B.o C.o

mytest.cpp: main.cpp
    cp -vf $< $@
mytest.o: CPPFLAGS += -DDEBUG
mytest.o: CXXFLAGS += -O0 -g
mytest: mytest.o Foo.o Bar.o Test.o A.o B.o C.o
```

This works because [built-in rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Implicit-Rules) exist for compiling objects from c++ source (`%.o: %.cpp`) and linking main programs (`%: %.o`).

Also note the use of [target-specific](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Target_002dspecific) values for the variables `CPPFLAGS` and `CXXFLAGS`.