# A .c file collection with their main() in NetBeans

Tags: c, netbeans, program-entry-point

I'm using NetBeans 7.0.1 to learn C.
I have done all the pre-requisites to start compiling in NetBeans so I'm ok with that.
I have done a "HelloWorld.c" with a `main()` in it and it runs fine. But then I made "Another.c" with its respective `main()`. I got an error which describes that I have already declared a `main()`.

How can I have a .c files collection in the same project with their respective `main`s? I'm doing this because I require the learning of the language since I switched some roles at work.

Is there a way so NetBeans can handle all the .c without a project? Or should i try this in Visual Studio 2010?

Comment: There can only be one `main()` function in a program. Start a new project in netbeans.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you can only have one `main()` per executable, but you're compiling the two files into on executable. When it links them it's spotting that the `main()` function exists in both of the files it's linking together and consequently reports this.

The solution is to make netbeans build you two, separate executables from each file. The easiest way to do this is to simply make two independent projects.

There is also a [slightly messy way of making this work within a single netbeans project](http://forums.netbeans.org/topic2950.html&highlight=), but I wouldn't recommend it unless you have a compelling reason. The other workaround would be to [write your own makefile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5191436/creating-two-separate-executables-from-a-makefile-g) to build two binaries, instead of using the netbeans managed one.